Is there a way for me to render an 3D model in my a-scene component that is a .glb?
I have a .glb file that contains a 3D model for a human dressed in a suit.
I want to show this model in my scene.
I use the following code to attempt this:
Within MyComponent.tsx, I return the following JSX
<a-scene embedded>
        <a-assets>
          <a-asset-item id="businessMan1" src="BusinessMan.glb"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>

        <a-gltf-model
          gltf-model="#businessMan1"
          position="0 0 0"
        ></a-gltf-model>
</a-scene>

My folder structure is

src

components

BusinessMan.glb
MyComponent.tsx





In the console I see that the model is not found
core:propertyTypes:warn "#businessMan1" asset not found. 

And in the a-frame inspector tool I can see the entity (but the 3D model is missing)

See picutre of my a-frame inspector tool view here
I have searched for many hours and attempted solutions found in other questions similar to mine, however I cannot seem to figure out exactly why I cannot see my 3D model when my syntax follows the documentation.
I have tried using a-entity, and upon doing research found that maybe I should try using a-gltf-model, however no matter what I do I seem to be hitting a wall.
I also see many of these questions/answers are 7+ years old. Is a-frame lib totally deprecated or can someone show me a simple example of rendering a 3D model stored in .gltf in a-scene in 2024?
I would love to use some of the free resources online for cool 3D models stored as .gltf/.glb. The documentation suggests they are interchangeable but despite following the docs I cannot get a simple example working!
I am able to see objects like this (a simple grey/black rectangular prism just below the camera start point)
<a-scene embedded>
    <a-entity
          geometry="primitive: box; width: 6; height: 0.5; depth: 3"
          position="0 0 -1.5"
          material="color: #333"
    ></a-entity>
</a-scene>

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I am using vite with react (if you couldnt tell from my previous statements).
Is there some other way I am supposed to load and then render this asset in my scene?? Am I clipping inside the object because it is rendering very large and the camera is somehow inside? If this is the case, then why cant I see my model when I zoom out in the inspector?
Do I need to defer rendering until I fully load the resource? How would I use the event listeners to know exactly when my .glb file is ready to render? Would I control this with a useEffect? Am I crazy?
